# How to restart app in flutter IOS on user logout

Tags: flutter, navigation, provider

I wanted to restart app in IOS on logout. So that when that when the new user login it shows new data as per his/her account [restartApp](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) works fine for Android but for. IOS even [flutter_phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix) doesn't work. as it. does not work at OS. level. The problem is the data provider that I've bind in **main()** does not call them again or **dispose()** them on logout.

Please guide me what is the right way and how to tackle it!

Here is how i'm navigating. to login screen

```
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();

  Navigator.of(context,rootNavigator: true).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Login();
  },),(_) => false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [restart_app](https://pub.dev/packages/restart_app) plugin, which leverages native APIs to restart the entire app in OS level. It supports iOS platform as well as Android and Web.

Answer (score -1):

Use this package. [Link to package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix)

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

And you can use below code to restart app from root

```
Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```